# method Glide.with(Context) is not applicable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I want to display list of images from Firebase storage with Glide

[image]

Comment: Try using Glide.with(MainActivity.this)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful what you reference from within an anonymous inner class. It is one of the big gotchas in functional languages like javascript, but we see it sometimes in java too. Essentially the meaning of "this" changes depending on its context. So where you use it "this" does not reference the Activity, it is referencing the OnSuccessListener which does not inherit from Context, therefore the code fails.

There are probably lots of ways you can solve this. One is what Mohammed suggested MainActivity.this. Another is to deliberately define a variable to reference the context before your code to add the listener.

> final Context context = getContext()

then you can freely reference that context variable from within your success listener.

> public void onSuccess(Uri uri){
>      Glide.with(context).load(uri)... 
>   }